SQL: Comparing Identical Rows in Different Tables and then Updating
I have these two tables : old_table was created on 2020-01-01 and  new_table was created on 2020-01-02.
CREATE TABLE old_table (
    name1 VARCHAR(50),
    name2 VARCHAR(50),
    origin_date DATE,
    var1 VARCHAR(50),
    today DATE
);


INSERT INTO old_table (name1, name2, origin_date, var1, today) VALUES
('red_1', 'red', '2010-01-01', 'aaa', '2020-01-01'),
('red_2', 'red', '2011-01-01', 'bbb', '2020-01-01'),
('blue_1', 'blue', '2005-01-01', 'ccc', '2020-01-01'),
('green_1', 'green', '2005-01-01', 'ddd', '2020-01-01');


CREATE TABLE new_table (
    name1 VARCHAR(50),
    name2 VARCHAR(50),
    origin_date DATE,
    var1 VARCHAR(50),
    today DATE
);


INSERT INTO new_table (name1, name2, origin_date, var1, today) VALUES
('purple_1', 'purple', '2001-01-01', 'fff', '2020-01-02'),
('pink_1', 'pink', '2002-01-01', 'ggg', '2020-01-02'),
('red_1', 'red', '2010-01-01', 'aaa', '2020-01-02');

I am trying to accomplish the following task:

I want to join both tables together (based on name1) and create new variables: status (active or inactive), end_date (today from new_table or NA).
The final result should have unique rows from old_table and unique rows from old_table.
The joined table will show the "life history" . Between the old_table and new_table... which rows "died" , which rows "survived" and which new rows were "born"
The status variable can only have values (active, inactive)
If a name survives, the end_date is always NULL and the status is always active. If a name does not survive, the end_date is the today date in the new file and the status is always inactive.

As an example: in the final dataset (i.e. after the sql code) ... green would have a origin date of 2005-01-01 and have an end_date of 2020-01-02 .red_1 survived in both old_table and new_table. therefore, red_1 can not have an end_date and its status must still be active.
The final result should look like this:
     name1  name2 origin_date var1  status   end_date
    red_1    red  2010-01-01  aaa  active       <NA>
    red_2    red  2011-01-01  bbb inactive 2020-01-02
   blue_1   blue  2005-01-01  ccc inactive 2020-01-02
  green_1  green  2005-01-01  ddd inactive 2020-01-02
purple_1 purple  2001-01-01  fff  active       <NA>
  pink_1   pink  2002-01-01  ggg  active       <NA>

I tried to write the following code using CTEs:
WITH combined AS (
    SELECT 
        old_table.name1, 
        old_table.name2, 
        old_table.origin_date, 
        old_table.var1, 
        new_table.today AS end_date, 
        CASE WHEN new_table.name1 IS NULL THEN 'inactive' ELSE 'active' END AS status
    FROM 
        old_table
    LEFT JOIN 
        new_table ON old_table.name1 = new_table.name1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        new_table.name1, 
        new_table.name2, 
        new_table.origin_date, 
        new_table.var1, 
        NULL AS end_date, 
        'active' AS status
    FROM 
        new_table
    WHERE 
        new_table.name1 NOT IN (SELECT name1 FROM old_table)
)
SELECT * FROM combined;

The code ran:
    name1  name2 origin_date var1 end_date   status
    red_1    red  2010-01-01  aaa       NA   active
    red_2    red  2011-01-01  bbb       NA inactive
   blue_1   blue  2005-01-01  ccc       NA inactive
  green_1  green  2005-01-01  ddd       NA inactive
 purple_1 purple  2001-01-01  fff       NA   active
   pink_1   pink  2002-01-01  ggg       NA   active

Problem: all the end_dates are NA - when some of them should be non NA (i.e. red_1, purple_1, pink_1).
Can someone please show me how to fix this?
Thanks!

Are you looking to just query the combined content of the two tables one time, or is this going to be an ongoing process where updated new_table data is periodically applied to form a constantly evolving history?

what could you want to do with the new table. All the records in the new_table are always active and all of the records in old_table are inactive. You would like to have a UNIONED recordset from both

Please update your question with a DBMS tag, such as sql-server, oracle, mysql, or whatever applies. You will reach a wider audience and are more likely to get a workable answer from those knowledgeable in that DBMS.

@ T N:this will be an evolving process ... the first time, I thought I need to start by building the cumulative table ... and then adding to it?

Have you considered using full outer join? ref
select
      coalesce(n.name1,o.name1) name1
    , coalesce(n.name2,o.name2) name2
    , coalesce(n.origin_date,o.origin_date) origin_date
    , coalesce(n.var1,o.var1) var1
    , case when n.name1 IS NULL then o.today end end_date
    , case when n.name1 IS NULL then 'inactive' else 'active' end status
from new_table n
full outer join old_table o on n.name1 = o.name1
order by
      coalesce(n.origin_date,o.origin_date) DESC 
    , coalesce(n.name1,o.name1) 




name1
name2
origin_date
var1
end_date
status




red_2
red
2011-01-01
bbb
2020-01-01
inactive


red_1
red
2010-01-01
aaa
null
active


blue_1
blue
2005-01-01
ccc
2020-01-01
inactive


green_1
green
2005-01-01
ddd
2020-01-01
inactive


pink_1
pink
2002-01-01
ggg
null
active


purple_1
purple
2001-01-01
fff
null
active



fiddle

I think I figured something out ...an additional CASE WHEN statement can target this problem?
WITH combined AS (
    SELECT 
        old_table.name1, 
        old_table.name2, 
        old_table.origin_date, 
        old_table.var1, 
        CASE WHEN new_table.name1 IS NULL THEN old_table.today ELSE NULL END AS end_date, 
        CASE WHEN new_table.name1 IS NULL THEN 'inactive' ELSE 'active' END AS status
    FROM 
        old_table
    LEFT JOIN 
        new_table ON old_table.name1 = new_table.name1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        new_table.name1, 
        new_table.name2, 
        new_table.origin_date, 
        new_table.var1, 
        NULL AS end_date, 
        'active' AS status
    FROM 
        new_table
    WHERE 
        new_table.name1 NOT IN (SELECT name1 FROM old_table)
)
SELECT * FROM combined;

Now, the end_date and status variables look correct:
     name1  name2 origin_date var1   end_date   status
    red_1    red  2010-01-01  aaa       <NA>   active
    red_2    red  2011-01-01  bbb 2020-01-01 inactive
   blue_1   blue  2005-01-01  ccc 2020-01-01 inactive
  green_1  green  2005-01-01  ddd 2020-01-01 inactive
 purple_1 purple  2001-01-01  fff       <NA>   active
   pink_1   pink  2002-01-01  ggg       <NA>   active

